# build appbundle errors :Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aPbo.png)
this is my probeme :
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 4316 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons fl
ag when building your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key upload from store "C:\Users\dell\StudioProjects\test1\android\app\upload-keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 37s

i try to build my android app with flutter build appbundle:

Answer (score 0):

I think of incorrect password to .jks file

way 1. check to key.properties on password

way 2. regenrate to jks file